# itextsharp html to pdf with different oriontation

Tags: c#, itext

I need to create single pdf using few html pages. Actually HTMLs have tables. Each HTMLs(table) has different number of columns, hence it should have to export pdf with difference oriontations.

Eg :

- htmlPg1 --> 4 columns
- htmlPg2 --> 15 columns

According to above scenario, it is needed to comes up the first html page with portrait mode and second html with landscape.

in below 'Code block 02' **lst** is a list which having 2 attributes. (Please see 'Code Block 01')
If the **lst** Oriantation is assigned 0, it is considered as Landscape and otherwise portrait.

***Code Block 01***

```
public class PdfExportDoc
{
    public int Oriantation { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }
}
```

All are working correctly except the orientation.

***Code Block 02***

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var doc = new Document())
            {
                using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
                {
                    doc.Open();                    

                    foreach (var ele in lst)
                    {
                        using (var srHtml = new StringReader(ele.Html))
                        {
                            if (ele.Oriantation == 0)
                            {
                                doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                            }
                            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                            doc.NewPage();                                
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
```

htmlPg1 data dragged for 2 pages and htmlPg2 has only one. This is how the data comes as pdf.

[image: Image 01 (Actually Data comes like this. But this is wrong)]

But actually I need the pdf like this.

[image]

Please show me a direction for doing this.

Comment: I deleted my answer. If it didn't work for you, I didn't interpret your question correctly. This being said: I think my answer was correct (I am the original developer of iText), and if anyone else answers, I think you'll get the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.
I get your point Bruno. You have said in your deleted answer NewPage will not added a new page if it is blank. So I added doc.NewPage to both before and after creating paraseXHtml. How ever thanks for your previous direction.

```
                    foreach (var ele in lst)
                        {
                            using (var srHtml = new StringReader(ele.Html))
                            {                               

                                if (ele.Oriantation == 1)
                                {
                                    doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                                }
                                doc.NewPage();
                                XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                                doc.NewPage();
                            }
                        }
```